# Why there are size limits in uploading files through the browser?

Tags: web, file-upload, limit, dropbox, filesize

Why the file hosting apps like **DropBox** set the limit of uploading file (now 50 GB) through the web browser, but from desktop apps there are no file size limits? 
 
What it depends on and why it happens? 
 
How correctly to transfer large files through the browser and why through desktop applications do it better?

*Google it but nothing found*

Comment: Browsers tend to have issues with enormous files, and resuming interrupted transfers. Do you really want to redo your transfer from the beginning after getting to 49 GB?

Comment: Browsers tend to have this issue because of internal architecture or mb because of network protocols?